# Parallel circuit calculations

Tags: ohms-law, calculation

This is definitely a very simple question for those in this community but I’m in a bit of a jam here. I did a lab where we simply measured the current, voltage and resistance on a low voltage trainer. I would upload the chart but apparently the file is too large. So for example I had measured 29.3ohms, 5.795V & 36.2mA in the lab for light 1. My problem is currently that when I calculate the resistance for the calculated section using the basic Ohms law of course, I get a far greater number (EG 160.1ohms for lamp 1). I understand that there should be a variance just due to natural occurrences (which is obviously supposed to be the point of the lab) but not this great, correct? Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Aidan! You have to think about us when you ask a question: We don't know what you're working on. For example, we have no idea what a "trainer" is!

Comment: Did you measure the resistance of the lamp separately?  When it was unpowered?

Comment: To piggy back on @MarcusMüller comment, in order to help you we need some basic information. A schematic of the circuit you're working on would be a good start, with components(names/type) and values(resistance, voltage, etc.) labeled.

Comment: Do some research on metals usedi n lamp filaments focussing on thermal properties.

Comment: Assuming you use filament bulbs: the resistance of filament bulbs goes up when they heat up, so it matters when you did the measurements. The resistance measured when the bulb is cold will not match \$\frac{V}{I}\$ when V and I have been measured when the bulb is hot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to make a huge guessing leap about this lab work and imagine that you are dealing with a tungsten lamp and that your lab *trainer* made a resistance measurement of the lamp, when cold; but you then made voltage and current measurements with the lamp active and hot.

From your numbers, I find \$\frac{5.795\:\text{V}}{36.2\:\text{mA}}= 160.082873\:\Omega\$. That is also what you got when you arrived at the *calculated section* (of your workbook?)

The issue then is that the resistance measurement was taken under different conditions. The trainer resistance measurement was made with a cold filament, as the trainer resistance measurement uses a very small current. The trainer voltage and current measurements were taken after the filament had enough time to heat up and glow, and was at the time quite hot.

The specific resistance of tungsten varies from, for example, \$5.00\times 10^{−6}\:\Omega\cdot\text{cm}\$ at \$273.15^\circ\text{K}\$ to \$117.1\times 10^{−6}\:\Omega\cdot\text{cm}\$ at \$3655^\circ\text{K}\$. A more detailed table can be found [at this hypertextbook page](https://hypertextbook.com/facts/2004/DeannaStewart.shtml):

[image]

Assume for now that your resistance measurement of \$29.3\:\Omega\$ was made at about \$300^\circ\text{K}\$. The ratio of resistance (cold vs hot) is \$\frac{160.1\:\Omega}{29.3\:\Omega} \approx 5.464\$. If you look up that ratio on the above table then I think you will find that the likely temperature of the filament, when active and hot, is \$1200^\circ\text{K}\$.

This is likely all you need to explain the results you have provided in your question. Both measurements were correct. They just weren't made under the same experimental conditions.